# Getting multiple percentage from a reduce map of a json data

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, javascript-objects

I would like to apologize in advance if there's already question like this but I've been searching all day and I really can find anything.

I call an api that returns a response. Then I only get the details/data that I need and currently now have a json file with this sample value:

```
{
    "total": 563,
    "shipping_fee": 58,
    "e_charges": ???,
    "order_items": [
      {
        "item_id": 6291020872,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 88,
        "total": 88
      },
      {
        "item_id": 7755274567,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 150,
        "total": 150
      },
      {
        "item_id": 7980571205,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 45,
        "total": 45
      },
      {
        "item_id": 12612977930,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 280,
        "total": 280
      }
    ]
  }, ... {} {} {}....
```

My problem is that, I need to get the sum of all `total` in `order_items []` then after that, I need to add the `shipping_fee` and get 2 sets of percentage

1. 10%
2. 8%

Note that, I'm getting the values in run-time.

```
const resDetails = await request.post(baseURL, {
        data: viewData
    });

info = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await resDetails.json()));
```

This is where the json file came from:

```
orders = await info.data.orders.map((x) => (total: x.order_items.map(y =>  Number(y.order_price) * y.amount).reduce((total, y) => y+total),
        shipping_fee : Number(x.shipping_fee), 
        e_charges: Number(Number((x.order_items.map(y=>  Number(y.order_price) * y.amount).reduce((total, y) => Number(y+total)) + Number(x.shipping_fee)) * 0.1).toFixed()),
        order_items: x.order_items.map((y) => ({
             item_id : y.item_id, 
             quantity: y.amount, 
             price: Number(y.order_price),
             total: Number(y.order_price) * y.amount)}))
```

I was able to get the 10% but my main problem is adding the other 8% without doing mapping, reducing and adding the `shipping_fee` again.

```
Number(Number((x.order_items.map(y=>  Number(y.order_price) * y.amount).reduce((total, y) => Number(y+total)) + Number(x.shipping_fee)) * 0.1).toFixed())
```

I'm fairly new to the javascript/typescript world. I hope someone can help me find a more optimized way to achieve what I need. Thank you.

EDIT:
Here's the actual code:
[image]

Comment: I believe the above is an input for you to process.  I see `shipping_fee` and `e_charges` (with ??) are already added.

Can you please separate the structures: what you get as as input and what you want as an output?

Comment: @RiteshJagga i'm calling an api that returns a json. I need to get those details and put it on a json file which contains only that data I need. The json file above is already the actual extraction from the response.

Answer (score 0):

You may please go through the below code. I'm not a big fan of doing `map`, `reduce` and calculations in single line because it takes away the readability. So, I broken down the calculations to a number of methods.

At the end, order `total` is calculated only once and saved the `e_charges` percentages in 2 different keys `e_charges_8` and `e_charges_10`, which I believe you can modify as per your need.

```js
let orders = [
  {
    "shipping_fee": 58,
    "order_items": [
      {
        "item_id": 6291020872,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 88
      },
      {
        "item_id": 7755274567,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 150
      },
      {
        "item_id": 7980571205,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 45
      },
      {
        "item_id": 12612977930,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 280
      }
    ]
  }, 
  {
    "shipping_fee": 58,
    "order_items": [
      {
        "item_id": 6291020872,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 88
      },
      {
        "item_id": 7755274567,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 150
      },
      {
        "item_id": 7980571205,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 45
      },
      {
        "item_id": 12612977930,
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 280
      }
    ]
  }
]


const getOrderItemTotal = (orderItem) => {
  return orderItem.quantity * orderItem.price
}

const getPercentage = (shippingFee, total, percentage) => {
  return ((total + shippingFee) * percentage).toFixed()
}

const getOrderItemsTotal = (orderItems) => {
  return orderItems.reduce((total, orderItem) => (total + orderItem.total), 0)
}

orders = orders.map(order => {
  order.order_items.map(orderItem => {
    orderItem.total = getOrderItemTotal(orderItem)
    return orderItem
  })
  
  order.total = getOrderItemsTotal(order.order_items)
  
  order.e_charges_8 = getPercentage(order.shipping_fee, order.total, 0.1)
  order.e_charges_10 = getPercentage(order.shipping_fee, order.total, 0.08)
    
  return order
})


console.log(orders)
```

Comment: Sorry for not so being clear. I updated the post.